# Istio pod-to-pod communication delivers packets to the app directly; skipping the proxy

Tags: kubernetes, istio

We are observing a weird behavior in istio mesh. We have an application with several services. Today we realized that the requests coming to one of the the services are failing. Checking the logs, we see that the packets are being directly delivered to the "app" container, instead of "istio-proxy".

I don't know if anyone can reproduce this, but what I did is to create a separate demo namespace and deployed two services (nginx and debian with curl). When I curl nginx from debian, I get this:

```
upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure/
```

These are the logs of istio-proxy container:

```
2020-10-20T16:32:32.914079Z     info    sds     node:sidecar~10.1.11.212~nginx.demo~demo.svc.cluster.local-1 resource:ROOTCA new connection
2020-10-20T16:32:32.914436Z     info    sds     node:sidecar~10.1.11.212~nginx.demo~demo.svc.cluster.local-2 resource:default new connection
2020-10-20T16:32:33.001150Z     info    cache   Root cert has changed, start rotating root cert for SDS clients
2020-10-20T16:32:33.001310Z     info    sds     node:sidecar~10.1.11.212~nginx.demo~demo.svc.cluster.local-2 resource:default pushed key/cert pair to proxy
2020-10-20T16:32:33.001322Z     info    sds     node:sidecar~10.1.11.212~nginx.demo~demo.svc.cluster.local-2 resource:default pushed secret
2020-10-20T16:32:33.114361Z     info    sds     node:sidecar~10.1.11.212~nginx.demo~demo.svc.cluster.local-1 resource:ROOTCA pushed root cert to proxy
2020-10-20T16:32:33.114388Z     info    sds     node:sidecar~10.1.11.212~nginx.demo~demo.svc.cluster.local-1 resource:ROOTCA pushed secret
2020-10-20T16:32:34.789815Z     info    Envoy proxy is ready
```

These are the logs of nginx container

```
10.1.11.100 - - [20/Oct/2020:16:34:18 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xCE\x01\x00\x00\xCA\x03\x03\x13`\xD9\xF6\xBD%\xF0\x88\x8B\x08m\xD98ZG\x90\x13\x8CI\xBA\x02\x0E\x0F" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
10.1.11.100 - - [20/Oct/2020:16:34:18 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xCE\x01\x00\x00\xCA\x03\x03\x01Y\xB0\x5CT \xC8:d\xD0|G\xF2\x04\xCD\x15-\xBFE(\xF4b'\xA08\x8B\xD5\xF1\x8D\xDF-s\x00\x00\x1C\xC0+\xCC\xA9\xC0/\xCC\xA8\xC0\x09\xC0\x13\x00\x9C\x00/\xC0,\xC00\xC0" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
10.1.11.100 - - [20/Oct/2020:16:34:18 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xCE\x01\x00\x00\xCA\x03\x03N\xEB\xA7tq\xBC\xB9\x8AR\x98A0J\xF6\x88I#\xCF~\xE8\xD7\xD4pO\x09\x14\x90\xEE\x08\x94\x1D\x8C\x00\x00\x1C\xC0+\xCC\xA9\xC0/\xCC\xA8\xC0\x09\xC0\x13\x00\x9C\x00/\xC0,\xC00\xC0" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
10.1.11.100 - - [20/Oct/2020:16:35:02 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xCE\x01\x00\x00\xCA\x03\x03\x9A\xF1\xE4)\xEF\xCB\xBA\xD4\xA9\xC2\x14\x04e\x9A\x84\x11&q\x9E\xC0\xF1&l\xE8\xCF\xE3\x1C\x94k2\xCF\xE1\x00\x00\x1C\xC0+\xCC\xA9\xC0/\xCC\xA8\xC0\x09\xC0\x13\x00\x9C\x00/\xC0,\xC00\xC0" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
10.1.11.100 - - [20/Oct/2020:16:35:02 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xCE\x01\x00\x00\xCA\x03\x03<\xEB\xA6W\xCB\x08miMl\x1A~\xD5\xA6DTm\xD5\xE83\xED\xDE\x8C}\xDF*4H\x87\xDC?\xE8\x00\x00\x1C\xC0+\xCC\xA9\xC0/\xCC\xA8\xC0\x09\xC0\x13\x00\x9C\x00/\xC0,\xC00\xC0" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
10.1.11.100 - - [20/Oct/2020:16:35:02 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xCE\x01\x00\x00\xCA\x03\x03\xDC\xD7\xF2-\x05ZD\xA3^L\x01\x07j\x1AW5@\x08\xC5\xCA\xFF\x90\xBB\xC9R\xF7|\xD2\xFC9,\x98\x00\x00\x1C\xC0+\xCC\xA9\xC0/\xCC\xA8\xC0\x09\xC0\x13\x00\x9C\x00/\xC0,\xC00\xC0" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
```

If you check the timestamp of the logs, you will see that all the requests went to the nginx container directly. Also, we know that this output is typical from nginx server when you send encrypted packets to endpoints that expect plain text. So, we think that the packets are being encrypted in one end, and being delivered to nginx directly; without passing through the proxy to be decrypted.

Now all the new created services fail with this issue, and the remaining services work just fine. We removed the mesh for now, to figure out what is going on.

We are using Istio 1.5.2, with mTLS enabled.

Comment: The same situation happens if you deploy it in the default namespace? It's clean 1.5.2 install or you have upgraded it from older version?

Comment: In any namespace. If it is in the mesh, it fails. We upgraded it from 1.4.7

Comment: Is there anything in the istiod logs? Have you tried with something else than debian? Everything is synced if you check with `istioctl ps`?